Apache and Reverse Proxy Issue
I have a server that is hosting some API's (we'll call it API-1).  I also have a server that is hosting files that developers can use to incorporate an iFrame into their website.  When they try to call the API's on API-1 via jQuery, they get CORS errors which I would expect.  So, on the server that is hosting the iFrame files, I have also setup a reverse proxy using Apache (PROXY-1).  However, I feel like I've still got something wrong because I get this error in Chrome:
https://api-1.somedomain.com/v1/api/function' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
Even though the jQuery is communicating with PROXY-1, the error message is still coming back for API-1.
Here is a snippet from my Apache config from PROXY-1:
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAlias *.somedomain.com
     SSLEngine On
     SSLProxyEngine On
     DocumentRoot /var/WWW/public
     SSLCertificateFile /SSL/secure.somedomain.com/secure.somedomain.com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /SSL/secure.somedomain.com/secure.somedomain.com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /SSL/secure.somedomain.com/secure.somedomain.com_bundle.crt
     Header always unset X-Frame-Options
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"

    ProxyPass "/authenticate" "https://api-1.somedomain.com/v1/utilities/authenticate"
    ProxyPassReverse "/authenticate" "https://api-1.somedomain.com/v1/utilities/authenticate"
    ProxyPass "/function" "https://api-1.somedomain.com/v1/api/function"
    ProxyPassReverse "/function" "https://api-1.somedomain.com/v1/api/function"

</VirtualHost>

I have tried messing with the headers as you'll see in the config but just can't seem to get this right.  Would really appreciate any advice!  Thank you!

Does it actually say from origin 'null' in the error message? That usually means the origin wasn't accessed via HTTP(S) to begin with, but only via the local file system. Is your proxy is actually passing the Origin header of the original request?

Are you trying to hide where those API calls are actually going to, from the frontend user? Or why did you decide to solve this via a proxy?

@C3roe Thank you for the reply!  Yes, it has null in the error message.  I decided to use the proxy because we were getting a ton of CORS errors when they tried to call the API server directly in the jQuery.  So I'm trying to "protect" the API server and use the proxy on the front end.

Why not make the API server respond with the appropriate headers to allow this cross-origin request, in the first place?

"Even though the jQuery is communicating with PROXY-1" - are you sure about that? The error message is still coming from the browser itself, by the looks of it. And I don't see why the browser should talk about a request to https://api-1.somedomain.com/- unless you made a client-side request for that origin ...?

@C3roe I'm definitely sure which is why I'm so stumped.  I have triple-checked the jQuery files to make sure there's no reference to the API-1 server.

Maybe your current setup is redirecting those requests back to https://api-1.somedomain.com/ somehow? What exactly do you see happen, when you monitor the request(s) and their responses in the network panel?

@C3roe Well I must have had something stuck in cache.  I just cleared my cache on my browser.  I'm still getting the error message, but this time it's referencing the proxy server:  https://proxy-1.somedomain.com/function' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header, but your client-side code apparently tries to set it as a request header. Remove it.

@C3roe That's part of what I've been struggling with.  If I remove that header from the Apache config, this is the error:  https://api-1.somedomain.com/authenticate' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If it's not your client-side code, then I'm guessing your proxy setup is messing up the headers somehow(?). Still not sure what the meaning of from origin 'null' is here to begin with - normally you'd get that, if the page you are making the request from, was not loaded via HTTP in the browser, but only accessed via the file system. If that's not what you are doing here - then I suspect the whole proxy thing might have something to do with that as well? (Although I can't currently see how.)
